# Setting a default value on join table from another table when model is edited or created

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hoping someone may be able to point me in the right direction.

I have a app that consists of (among other things) Recommendations and Assessments. They are joined with a join table that includes extra fields that I would like to update but am struggling to figure out how.

[image: Data model]

As you can see above, when I create a Reccommendation, I set the following fields:

- default_user_impact
- default_business_impact
- default_deployment_complexity
- default_criticality

Now when I create a new Assessment or edit one that has not got any Recommendations linked the Assessment saves fine because nothing is needing to be written to the join table.

When I try to edit an Assessment to include one or more Recommendations, the app tries to write the link to the join table and fails because the user_impact, business_impact, deployment_complexity and criticality fields aren't specified - perfectly normal because I have set the fields to required in MySQL right? The error I get in CakePHP is

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_impact' doesn't have a default value

What I want to be able to do is at the time of editing or creating an Assessment is to use the values in the Recommendations table to populate the corresponding join table entries. Any ideas how to go about this?

So as an example:

- user_impact = default_user_impact
- business_impact = default_business_impact
- deployment_complexity = default_deployment_complexity
- criticality = default_criticality

The reason I want to do this is so that I can have the Recommendations set with values for those fields, and then if a user wants to run an assessment and they want to adjust the values just for their own assessment then it won't impact others etc.

Here is my AssessmentsTable association.

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Recommendations', [
        'foreignKey' => 'assessment_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'recommendation_id',
        'joinTable' => 'assessments_recommendations',
        'through' => 'assessments_recommendations',
    ]);
```

Here is my RecommendationsTable association.

```
    $this->belongsToMany('Assessments', [
        'foreignKey' => 'recommendation_id',
        'targetForeignKey' => 'assessment_id',
        'joinTable' => 'assessments_recommendations',
        'through' => 'assessments_recommendations',
    ]);
```

Here is my AssessmentsRecommendations association:

```
    $this->belongsTo('Assessments', [
        'foreignKey' => 'assessment_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
    $this->belongsTo('Recommendations', [
        'foreignKey' => 'recommendation_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
```

This is what my AssessmentsController edit function looks like:

```
public function edit($id = null)
{
    $assessment = $this->Assessments->get($id, [
        'contain' => ['Recommendations'],
    ]);

    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
        $assessment = $this->Assessments->patchEntity($assessment, $this->request->getData(), ['associated'=>['Recommendations._joinData']]);            
        if ($this->Assessments->save($assessment, ['associated' => ['Recommendations._joinData']])) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('The assessment has been saved.'));       

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The assessment could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $clients = $this->Assessments->Clients->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $recommendations = $this->Assessments->Recommendations->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
    $this->set(compact('assessment', 'clients', 'recommendations'));
}
```

Now when I've added the beforeSave function to the AssessmentsRecommendationsTable I see the following error:

> Argument 2 passed to App\Model\Table\AssessmentsRecommendationsTable::beforeSave() must be an instance of App\Model\Table\EntityInterface, instance of Cake\ORM\Entity given, called in /var/www/html/csa-portal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php on line 310

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which cakephp version are you using?

Comment: I'm using CakePHP 4.0.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the associations you are using are wrong. It should be like this

> For AssessmentsTable

```
   $this->hasMany('AssessmentsRecommendations', [
        'foreignKey' => 'assessment_id'
   ]);
```

> For RecommendationsTable

```
   $this->hasMany('AssessmentsRecommendations', [
        'foreignKey' => 'recommendation_id'
   ]);
```

> For AssessmentsRecommendationsTable

```
    $this->belongsTo('Assessments', [
        'foreignKey' => 'assessment_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);

    $this->belongsTo('Recommendations', [
        'foreignKey' => 'recommendation_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER',
    ]);
```

Now for the default values, you have to user [beforeSave](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave) in you **AssessmentsRecommendationsTable.php** file.You can modify your data as per your need here before the save.

```
public function beforeSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity, \ArrayObject $options)
    {
        if ($entity->isNew()) { // Returns true when you add new record
            $recommendation = TableRegistry::getTableLocator()->get('Recommendations')->get($entity->recommendation_id);
            $entity->user_impact = $recommendation->default_user_impact;
            $entity->business_impact = $recommendation->default_business_impact;
            $entity->deployment_complexity = $recommendation->default_deployment_complexity;
            $entity->criticality = $recommendation->default_criticality;
        }
    }
```

- I have never used **belongsToMany**, if the associations works for you then ignore the association part.

Comment: Thanks for this Aman. I'm testing out your beforeSave event as this seems logical to me. I'm getting this error when saving an Assessment though. By the way, I kept my associations as they seem to work fine. Hoping that is not the issue.

**Argument 2 passed to App\Model\Table\AssessmentsRecommendationsTable::beforeSave() must be an instance of App\Model\Table\EntityInterface, instance of Cake\ORM\Entity given, called in /var/www/html/csa-portal/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Event/EventManager.php on line 310**

I've added my AssessmentsController edit function in the origianal post.

Comment: I've added the detail to the original post.

Comment: Can you try removing EntityInterface from the beforeSave like this `beforeSave(Event $event, $entity, \ArrayObject $options)`. As per the document  https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave it should be EntityInterface

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! This works - now to do some testing. Going to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered writing a Rule to handle this?

https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/validation.html#applying-application-rules

Comment: Thanks for the link. I had read that and a Rule was my initial thought but I'm at a complete loss as to how to implement a Rule against joinData.

Comment: Since the rule can be a callable, you can have as much logic as you need to accomplish your tasks. When you detect a change to the column that can lead to the problem, your rule could do any processes it needs to insure all the data will align correctly.

You may need to read the join record in directly to examine it before letting the save proceed?

Comment: If I'm following your problem correctly, your rule would apply to creation or edit of an assessment and if the connected join did not exist or had the wrong values, you would read the values from recommendations and set them for the save.

Comment: The rule would apply to creation or edit of an assessment yes. However, if I edit an assessment and say maybe I add an additional recommendation, I wouldn't want to update all the values for that assessment again, only for the newly added recommendation(s).

Comment: using the `dirty` and `getOriginal` methods on the entities you might be able to make your rule specific enough to target only the newly added recommendations.
https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/entities.html#checking-if-an-entity-has-been-modified

Comment: I'm curious about a detail of your setup. Do you have the third recommended association defined for belongs-to-many-through; the two belongsTo definitions on AssessmentsRecommendationsTable? (see this example: https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option).

There aren't any details in the docs that suggest this will solve your problem, but there may be some advantages that become clear.

Comment: I currently do have a third AssessmentsRecommendationsTable with the double belongsTo. I added it while going through the documentation while testing yesterday. I'm still struggling with this though. By the way, thank you for all your help so far. It is very much appreciated.